# Hadoop: time it takes to delete files permanently?

Tags: hadoop

I had a directory with around 300 GB of data which was probably also replicated 3 times.

I just deleted the files using `hadoop dfs -rmr` and I was wondering what Hadoop's process is for deleting the files? within seconds I got a message saying that it was deleted but how long would it take for the actual space to clear up for the 300GB and the replicated shards?

Im using Hadoop version 0.20.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadoop filesystem handles deletion operation in the same way as blocks creation upon file transfers to the HDFS. The hadoop dfs -rmr shell command is received by the name node which holds the metadata regarding the allocated blocks for a file(s) .The delete operation is informed to respective data nodes which then delete the blocks and their replications present on the disks.

The operation would take some significant time if run on a simple file on a non HDFS ,but since we are on a distributed environment ,time involved is reduced by many folds,say a 1000 GB file takes 100 seconds on a single non HDFS, would take 10 seconds on a ten data nodes HDFS.I hope that was helpful.